# Unable to determine interface type without an established connection Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a customize Framework to my project but when I ran the project the screen turn in black and got following error

**log:** 
`"unable to determine interface type without an established connection"` & `" unable to determine fallback status without a connection"`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011737/ios-13-tls-issue

Answer (score 2):

Its because as a safe connection could not be established may be because of security permissions or low internet quality.

1. Turn off your testing iPhone device and switch it ON again
   **If developer access is required for the project.**
   In the developer access section of the account used to develop the app on Xcode remove the iPhone for giving developer access on the device.
2. Connect the iPhone again and trust the computer. If any other apple device is active at the time with same account as used in iPhone, trust the macbook from those devices too. Finally give developer access if asked
3. Build the code again.